# rebar3: dependency is not reachable

Tags: erlang

I was trying to convert a REST API example built using rebar to rebar3 release (http://jordenlowe.com/title/Explain_like_I_am_5_-_Erlang_REST_Framework_Cowboy). I have added `jsx` to `app.src`.
What could be the reason for this? Also is there anything I need to do more when making this a rebar3 release?

This error comes up.

```
===> Failed to solve release:
Dependency jsx is specified as a dependency but is not reachable by the system.
```

Comment: A co-author of `rebar3` posted [the answer](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2016-January/087490.html) in the erlang-questions mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

It's not enough to add jsx to app.src file. You need to add this dependency(jsx) rebar.config file.

Your deps section in rebar.config must be something like

```
  {deps, [
            {cowboy, "1.0.1"}, % package
            {jsx,  "2.8.0"}
   ]}.
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answers and for the edit @Hamidreza Soleimani.
I added this line to `rebar.confid` and the error is gone.

```
{jsx, {git,"git://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx.git", {tag, "v2.7.1"}}}
```